# PHP - Footer function sample

Tags: php, sql

I've been looking all over but I cannot find an example. I want to write a foother function into my functions.php Can you please give me a simple sample of how this is done. I think I have an idea but I'm not sure if will work.

```
 function footer_function()
 {
   $return_Str='';
   $return_Str .= '<h3>Copyright © 2012</h>';
   return $return_Str;
}
```

Thank you all for your help!!!

Comment: Holy Cow. I didn't know that. I'll fix it right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you wanted.

```
function footer() {
    $return_str = "";
    $return_str .= '<h3>Copyright 2012</h3>';
    return $return_str;
}
```

To display the footer. Just do this

```
echo footer();
```

Comment: you misspelled "return" there.

Answer (score 2):

Just add function before the code so that it looks like this:

```
function footer_function()
{
   $return_Str = '';
   $return_Str .= '<h3>Copyright © '.date('Y').'</h>';
   return $return_Str;
}
```

Notice how I changed 2012 to the date function so that PHP will automatically change the data as required so that you don't have to manually update it every year.

To call the function you need to simply write this where you want the text to be displayed:

```
echo footer_function();
```

I would also suggest writing a template in HTML (or php) for your footer and then saving it as footer.inc.php. You could then include this file at the end of your document using this function:

```
include('footer.inc.php;);
```

This is so that you can easily edit the HTML for the entire site without updating the individual pages.

Answer (score 1):

your question is very generalized so im going to help as best I can. Ff you want to write html within php scrip you can do so like this, you also need to Echo it:

```
<?php
footer_function()
 {
  $return_Str='';
  $return_Str .= { ?>
   <h3>Copyright © 2012</h>
  <?php }
  return $return_Str;
 }
 echo footer_function();
 ?>
```

You see the {} act as a container for the HTML code between the php and will carry through multiple php flags until closed:

```
<?php
footer_function()
 {
  $return_Str='';
  $return_Str .= { ?>
   <h3>Copyright © 2012</h>
   <h1><?php someFunction(); ?></h1>
  <?php }
  return $return_Str;
 }
 echo footer_function();
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this in one of my projects:

```
<div id="footer">

    <div id="inner">

        <p><span class="color">Copyright © Hüseyin Zeki, 2012 </span> Tüm hakları saklıdır.</p>

        <ul>

            <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/Huskopat" class="facebook"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" class="twitter"></a></li>

        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

Php version:

```
function footer_function() {
$return_Str = '';
$return_Str .= '<div id="footer">';
$return_Str .='<div id="inner">';
$return_Str .='<p><span class="color">Copyright © Hüseyin Zeki, 2012 </span> Tüm hakları saklıdır.</p>';
$return_Str .='<ul>';
$return_Str .='<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/Huskopat" class="facebook"></a></li>';
$return_Str .='<li><a href="https://twitter.com/" class="twitter"></a></li>';
$return_Str .='</ul>';
$return_Str .='</div>';
$return_Str .='</div>';
return $return_Str;
}
```

Comment: This is what I have in my code. So let's say I want to add this footer as a function. then should I do this   function footer_function()
 {
   $return_Str='';
   $return_Str .= '<div id="footer">

    <div id="inner">

        <p><span class="color">Copyright © Hüseyin Zeki, 2012 </span> Tüm hakları saklıdır.</p>

        <ul>

            <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/Huskopat" class="facebook"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" class="twitter"></a></li>

        </ul>

    </div>

</div>';
   return $return_Str;
}

Comment: Awesome, can you use in your example my code? just so I can see it

Comment: Use this function (like modify for your needs) and follow Cameron's steps. Youre done.

Comment: What happen if you just say $return_Str .= 'the entire html here' instead of typing "$return_Str .=" in every line? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this for wordpress?

You've created a basic function which returns a string and your example will work depending on how you implement it... i.e.:

`echo footer_function();`

You should consider making the year dynammic instead of static.

`$returnStr .= '<h3>Copyright ".date('Y')."</h3>';`

Comment: Wowow , How do you do that? How do you make the year Dynammic? I'm learning a lot with just the basic question I had.

Comment: By using the PHP date() function.  date('Y') will return the current year in the "YYYY" format.  date('y') will return the date in YY format.  http://www.php.net/date